# Is it possible to directly run and debug react native apps on android devices without even installing android SDK?

Tags: android, react-native

I don't want install Android SDK on my laptop, so is that possible!

Comment: @jevakallio thanks for editing my question! by the way even iOS, ionic or whoever in the mobile development area could have an idea and that's why I mentioned them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using any 3rd party modules in your app you can:

- Develop your app on [React Native Playground](https://rnplay.org/)
- Install the [React Native Playground app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rnplay.playground) on your Android device
- Run on your device without installing Android SDK!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Josh ^^